# High Sierra - Bootable USB - Can't make

Tags: usb, startup

I have a problem with making bootable USB.

I'm getting this error:

```
Macintosh:~ **$ sudo /Applications/Install\ macOS\ High\ Sierra.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia --volume /Volumes/Untitled --applicationpath /Applications/Install\ macOS\ High\ Sierra.app
Ready to start.
To continue we need to erase the volume at /Volumes/Untitled.
If you wish to continue type (Y) then press return: y
APFS disks may not be used as bootable install media.
```

On the same usb drive I had Yosemite, but for some reason I can't make it work with High Sierra. Also tried to erase it in Disk Utility(no errors).

Can somebody help?

Comment: When erasing the USB drive, change the Format to `Mac OS Extended` and try creating the installer again.

Comment: @NimeshNeema that's the problem, I did(using disk utility) without errors, then I went back to the terminal and tried to create bootable usb again, but got the same error. Will try to restart macbook.

Comment: What format does Disk Utility say the volume is in?

Comment: @GordonDavisson I restarted Mac and everything works now. Thanks

Comment: Note that if the USB drive is formatted as APFS, you first need to delete the APFS volume in Disk Utility, before Disk Utility will give you the option to erase and reformat as a non-APFS file system; see https://dreamlight.com/how-to-reformat-an-apfs-drive-as-hfs-with-disk-utility/

Comment: @PaulD.Waite At least in Catalina (10.15.7), using Disk Utility's "Partition" instead of "Erase" will allow you to select non-APFS filesystems.

Answer (score 5):

I think the message is quite straightforward: It seems like your USB stick is formatted as APFS and the error message says that you can't.

Reformat the USB Stick using Mac OS Extended instead.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your Internal Disk is not called "Untitled" if so choose a different name for your USB. You can do `ls /Volumes` to see all your disk names.

Comment: Ah, this was my problem.  I apparently have another Untitled volume in my "Container disk1" that is pretty much empty.  I should have been pointing at `/Volumes/Untitled 1` (e.g. `--volume /Volumes/Untitled\ 1`)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, but solve it using Paragon free software to downgrade to HFS+, as the Disk Utility didn't have to option to erase it to that format.

https://www.paragon-software.com/home/apfs-hfs-converter/

Answer (score 0):

I also faced similar issue. When I verified the disk name I found that my **internal disk name** was also 'Untitled' as shown in below image.

So I changed USB device name and it worked.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

**I solved my problem**, do this step
Rename the USB Drive for:
HIGHSIERRA
(*rename in code also*)
This is solution. **:)**